# Dart unittest pgsql query error

Tags: dart

I've got some code in file **web_server.dart** which is placed in **bin** folder:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:redstone/server.dart' as app; 
import 'package:redstone_mapper/mapper.dart'; 
import 'package:redstone_mapper/plugin.dart'; 
import 'package:redstone_mapper_pg/manager.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart' as shelf; 

main() {
  var uri = "postgres://rpss:@10.10.10.10:5432/rty";
  var dbManager = new PostgreSqlManager(uri, min: 1, max: 3);
  app.addPlugin(getMapperPlugin(dbManager));
  app.setupConsoleLog();
  app.start(address: '127.0.0.1', port: 8100);
}

PostgreSql get pgsql => app.request.attributes.dbConn;

Future getNextPlanId() {
  return pgsql.query("select smth from table1", String);
}
```

There is another dart file named **web_server_test.dart** in **test** folder:

```
library web_server_test;

import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import '../bin/web_server.dart';

void main() {
    group('test1', () { 

     test("Step 1: must be PASS", (){
          return getNextPlanId().then((onValue){
              expect(onValue, hasLength(4));
          });
      });
  }); 
}
```

When I run **web_server_test.dart** file, I get an error:

Test failed: Caught The null object does not have a getter 'attributes'.
  NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'attributes'

I tryed to run web_server.dart or to stop one. The error is rising up.

Comment: I don't know how to fix your problem, just a suggestion. Don't import from other top-level directories using relative paths. If you want to import code from other top-level directories, move the code into the `lib` directory and use package imports like `import 'package:my_package/server.dart';` to import from there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your test you're not bootstrapping `app`. The code that's in your main has to be called for your test. The `main()` function isn't called automatically in your test.

You could extract its logic in a function and call it your test setup.

`PostgreSql get pgsql => app.request.attributes.dbConn;` crashed when you call `attributes` on `request`, it's probably not initialized like you would want it to be.